# Accidentally Delete PST Files Of Outlook

Tags: outlook, office365

I have accidentally deleted OUTLOOK 365 users*.pst files.

Then I have re-installed Office 365.

Now Outlook raises message at start up like "The file c:\users\onedrive\documents"outlook files..*.pst" cannot be found, and closes.

I have read recovery advices, but coluld not found scanpst.exe even.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you do shift-delete or just delete?

Comment: deleted from file explorer list, and then from RECYCLE BIN, namely there is no chance to recover these files, may I create manualy these file (mail addresses), thanks..

Comment: i found [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-outlook-data-files-pst-and-ost-25663bc3-11ec-4412-86c4-60458afc5253)

Comment: it says "exit outlook", but I can not even enter outlook, secondly do not know where to find "scanpst.exe". I did a search in all directories of C:\

Comment: it looks like `scanpst.exe` should be somewhere in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Outlook

Without Selecting a PST file, enter OPEN on coming Dialog Box

Enter Password you have already

Outlook Opens, Type 'Add Account' on Search Box, related tool comes

Add your Mail Accounts.